# How can I make ReSharper go into my own external sources while debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, nuget, resharper, external

Ever since I started using ReSharper it's never been clear to me how I can step into **my own** external sources. Sometimes it's working, but most of the times it is not.

As my frustrations are at its peak I would like to figure out how this works once and for all.

I have two C# solution files (one for my Framework and one for my Platform). I am using code from my Framework in my Platform solution through Nugets.
Both solutions are located on my disk (`C:\<project>\framework` and `C:\<project>\platform`). The Framework solution contains several projects (e.g. `Framework.Core` and `Framework.Logging`).

When I am debugging my Platform solution I cannot navigate into a method (F11) that is called on one of my Framework components.

[image: My ReSharper options]

As said, this has been working fine for me in the past but now it's not working anymore and I cannot find the solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So it "magically" started working again and I can step into my external sources again when debugging. I have not changed my options. So it must be something stupid but I don't know what...

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper doesn't control anything about stepping into external source while debugging. The options in your screenshot control *navigating* into external source from standard ReSharper navigation commands (go to type, find usages, etc).

In order to debug external sources, you'll need to make sure you have access to the `.pdb` files for your external code. This must either be side-by-side with the assembly, or available in the symbol cache, or downloaded from a symbol server.

Comment: Ok understood. But what do you mean about the `.pdb` files? They are (for instance) located in my `C:\<project>\framework\Framework.Core\bin\debug` folder. Whereas my `Platform` solution would reference `C:\<project>\platform\packages\Framework.Core\lib\net452\Framework.Core.dll` since I am using Nuget. How is it able to find the `.pdb`?

Comment: If the `.pdb` isn't next to the `.dll` file, it can be downloaded from a symbol server. Microsoft has one for the .net framework, some nuget packages [publish symbols](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package) to [symbolsource.org](http://www.symbolsource.org) (but the service is a bit flaky these days) and it's also possible to create your own symbol server. You can also use dotPeek to [decompile a `.pdb` on the fly](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/dotPeek+Symbol+Server+and+PDB+Generation).